# What is the difference between renderTracked and renderTriggered in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

What is the difference between renderTracked and renderTriggered in vue3?

the official explanation is here:
https://vue3js.cn/docs/zh/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#errorcaptured

I try a demo as below,the two Api got the same args.

```
renderTracked({ key, target, type }) {
   console.log('renderTracked:', { key, target, type });
},
renderTriggered({ key, target, type }) {
   console.log('renderTriggered:', { key, target, type });
},
```

Answer (score 2):

> renderTriggered

when set data, vue will call this function

> renderTracked

when data changed and view updated, will call this function，so renderTracked will called when initial render

Answer (score 0):

Both hooks are very useful for debugging.

`renderTriggered` contains info about what caused the re-render to happen (an event, setting of a prop or changing data for example). I think of it as a "before hook" (it happens before `renderTracked` same as `beforeUpdate` happens before `updated`).

`renderTracked` on another hand executes when the component initially renders and later re-renders.

Both are very similar, but the `renderTriggered` has more data to it. You lost it when destructuring the argument. Beside the `target`, `type` and `key`, the object has the following props:

```
{
  "newValue": "",
  "oldValue": "",
  "oldTarget": {}
}
```